# print array of NSString in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays

So I have a NSMutableArray of size 100, and I want to print 10 cells at a time (So it looks like a grid). What is the easiest way to print 10 indexes at a time? Thanks.

Here's what I did, it only prints 1 index at a time.

-(void) printBoard{

```
for(int i =0; i<_board.count; i++){
    NSLog(@"%@ |", [_board objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

Comment: Understand first off that NSLog is only intended for diagnostic printing, not "production".  Also understand that NSLog ALWAYS provides a "newline" character at the end, so the output of two NSLog statements will never be on the same line.  So either you need to aggregate your strings together before using NSLog, or not use NSLog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print a contiguous array as a two-dimensional array, you can use something like the following:

```
- (NSString *) description 
{
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];

    for (int y = 0; y < 100; y += 10)
    {
        NSArray *row = [_board subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(y, 10)];
        NSString *rowString = [row componentsJoinedByString:@" | "];
        [result appendFormat:@"%@\n", rowString];
    }

    return result;
}
```

If you put this instance method in your class then you can use `NSLog()` directly on your instance (that is instead of doing `[object printBoard]`  your would use `NSLog(@"%@", object);`).

Comment: I used  NSLog(@"%@",result); in my void method and it prints what i want. Thank you.